# SQL doesn't display new changes from query

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have this query which is written in MySQL on Visual Studio Code text editor

```
 CREATE TABLE largest_number (

        n INT NOT NULL,
    );
    
    INSERT INTO largest_number(n)
    VALUES 
    (1),
    (40),
    (300),
    (600),
    (10);
    
    SELECT MAX(n) AS Largest_Number FROM largest_number;
```

and I decided to add a new column called 'username':

```
CREATE TABLE largest_number (
    n INT NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(25)
);

INSERT INTO largest_number(n,username)
VALUES 
(1,"Dan"),
(400,"Daniel"),
(300,"Joseph"),
(600,"Adam"),
(10,"Adamza");

SELECT MAX(n) AS Largest_Number FROM largest_number;
```

When I executes the code it throws:

```
FAIL:

  INSERT INTO largest_number(n,username) VALUES (1,"Dan"), (400,"Daniel"), (300,"Joseph"), (600,"Adam"), (10,"Adamza")

Message :

  Unknown column 'username' in 'field list'
```

My main is problem is when I change the

```
INSERT INTO largest_number(n)
    VALUES 
    (1),
    (40),
    (300),
    (600),
    (10);
```

to:

```
INSERT INTO largest_number(n)
        VALUES 
        (15),
        (140),
        (1300),
        (1600),
        (110);
```

The output doesn't display the new changes and displays the old values, I have been stressing over this for days why is this happening?. Googling doesn't help too.

Comment: Does "n" column have primary key?
Looks like you can not see any type of mysql errors there. So when error throws current transaction will be declined. And you will see old values.

Comment: @L0ndl3m No it doesn't?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see a definition in your post. Here is not a key problem i think.
Did you try to drop and create again "largest_number" table with new "username" field?

Comment: Is this working?

Comment: @L0ndl3m Yes it works I appreciated it